# How Can I Assign the Results from Object Oriented Mysqli Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to assign the results from a mysqli prepared statement query, but I am having trouble assigning the results to my variables.  I have tried several methods, and have confirmed that my query is running and returing data.

Here is how I am trying to assign the results:

```
if ( $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `email`, a.`$colname`
                                FROM `li_appointments`.`li_appointments` AS a
                                LEFT JOIN `lidb_users`.`login_users` AS b ON a.`created_by` = b.`username`
                                WHERE a.`app_id` = ?
                                LIMIT 1;")) {
    $stmt1->bind_param("s", $id);
    $return1 = $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->bind_result($z, $name);
        while($stmt1->fetch()) {
               $to_email = $email;
               $oldvalue = $$colnam;
                        }   
    $stmt1->close();
    }
```

Why are these not being assigned to the variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't works because you're trying to get values from $email and $$colnam

bind_result takes as params all variable that needs to be filled by datas from your query. So in your declaration, you have $z and $name but you don't call them.

You have to assign to $to_email the value of $z and assign to $oldvalue, the value of $name like this

```
while ($stmt1->fetch()) {
    $to_email = $z;
    $oldvalue = $name;
}
```

Please note that $$colnam is a dynamic call of var in PHP.
If you have the following code :

```
$message = 'hi!';
$burger = 'message';
echo $$burger;
```

It will outputs 'hi!' because it will read the value of $burger which is 'message' and dynamically call $message

Answer (score 3):

You've bound the two columns to `$z` and `$name`, but then you try to access them via `$email` and `$$colnam`.

Use the variables you bound to:

```
while($stmt1->fetch()) {
    $to_email = $z;
    $oldvalue = $name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to the prepared statements.